# NordVPN on Draytek 2862 stops working after some time for no apparent reason

Tags: vpn, ipsec, draytek

So i have a NordVPN account, which i configured on my draytek, it works for the most part but it will suddenly stop working. the connect does NOT drop, it shows as connected and fine, but no devices have internet. I have to manually press the drop button and wait for it to reconnect after a few seconds, then everything will be fine again... The problem is that i cannot be doing that all the time. It drops calls (on VoIP) and i am not on site.

Draytek don't know, and nor does Nord... I have tried everything that i know.

Nothing shows in the logs. I have set up the IKE advanced settings perfectly as per Nords instructions.

If you want to see the configuration i used please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Could be your internet connection itself. If the connection drops NordVPN has to reconnect, do have any options regarding a reconnect of NordVPN?

Comment: i should have mentioned i know it's not that, ive gone through several lines and also testet that already :)